# Unable to generate Java classes from JSON Schema using JsonSchema2Pojo-maven-plugin

Tags: jsonschema2pojo

I have used the following URL to understand the usage of JsonSchema2Pojo plugin https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started#the-maven-plugin

However, I am unable to generate any class for the address schema. I have followed the same step as mentioned in the source but still no java class has been generated for address schema. I don't understand what can I do now.
Please help me with a proper explanation.

Comment: I know it is a little late, but I could help you get that working.  Could you include details about exactly what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Double check your pom.xml and your project setup.  The instructions on the wiki worked for me, here are the steps I took (OSX)

1. Generate the initial project and pom.xml

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.stackoverflow.example -DartifactId=example -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
   ```
2. Download the address schema to ./src/main/resources/schema/address.json
3. Update the pom.xml as described on the JsonSchema2Pojo documentation
4. Generate the files

   ```
   $ find . -type f
   ./pom.xml
   ./src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/example/App.java
   ./src/main/resources/schema/address.json
   ./src/test/java/com/stackoverflow/example/AppTest.java
   $ mvn package
   ```
5. Generated files will be under **./target/java-gen** directory

   ```
   $ find . -name Address.java
   ./target/java-gen/com/example/types/Address.java
   ```